# Docker-compose yml ошибка при запуске контейнер php

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Есть образ php
 В docker-compose.yml

```
php:
    image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6
    container_name: lemp_php
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./project:/var/www/
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db**
```

Изначально строчка

```
volumes:
          - ./project:/var/www/
```

была

```
volumes:
              - ./project:/var/www/html
```

и образ запускался.
Поменял строчку на **- ./project:/var/www/**

Выводится ошибка

**ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"chdir to cwd (\\"/var/www/html\\") set in config.json failed: no such file or directory\"\n"
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в качестве working directory указан /var/www/html, которого при таком биндинге не существует, о чем вам явно говорит ошибка. Либо создайте эту директорию, либо смените ее в параметрах запуска.

```
php:
    image: evild/alpine-php:7.0.6
    ...
    working_dir: /var/www
```

Comment: Спасибо, решило проблему